# How to fix the NumPy .dtype 'NoneType' error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am running the following Python code in PyCharm debug mode.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, numpy.polynomial.chebyshev as chebyshev
from pathlib import Path

home = str(Path.home())

directory = '/Downloads'
d = pd.read_csv(home+directory+'/data.csv')

np.random.seed(0)
nData = 4
data = np.random.randn(nData,2)
z = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

coef = chebyshev.chebfit(z,y,3)
```

I encounter the following error message :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

However if I comment out the line 'd = ...', everything works fine. What is even more bizarre is that both versions run well in the run mode. What is happening here?

Stack trace for the error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --cmd-line --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 65032 --file /Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/trial.py
warning: PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON environment variable is set to 'NO'. Frame evaluator will be also disabled because it requires Cython extensions to be enabled in order to operate correctly.
/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py:1844: DeprecationWarning: currentThread() is deprecated, use current_thread() instead
  dummy_thread = threading.currentThread()
Connected to pydev debugger (build 212.5457.59)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py", line 384, in __new__
    dtype = numeric.dtype(dtype)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/trial.py", line 16, in <module>
    coef0 = chebyshev.chebfit(z0,y0,4)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/polynomial/chebyshev.py", line 1670, in chebfit
    return pu._fit(chebvander, x, y, deg, rcond, full, w)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/polynomial/polyutils.py", line 650, in _fit
    rcond = len(x)*np.finfo(x.dtype).eps
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py", line 387, in __new__
    dtype = numeric.dtype(type(dtype))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you please provide this info: numpy version, full stack trace, a.dtype?

Comment: Try this again in a fresh script or session.

Comment: @hpaulj: I have isolated the point of failure and edited the question. It is very strange.

Comment: @jhso: I have isolated the point of failure and edited the question. It is very strange.

Comment: As a side not: if you're already using `pathlib`, use `Path.home() / 'Downloads' / 'data.csv'`.

Comment: You need a PyCharm tag.  This isn't a numpy issue;

Comment: Since this involves a pandas file read, and pycharm debug mode this isn't reproducible, and unless one of us has previously banged our head on the issue, we can't help.  You could, I suppose, examine `d` after the read, and also check `y` and `z` before passing them the `chebfit`.  and try the `finfo` on each of them.  As you say without the file read, and without pycharm, the rest of the code runs just fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Please upgrade to pandas >= 1.4.3 to fix this problem**. You'd need to downgrade to Python 3.9, or *upgrade to pandas 1.4.3*.

This *was* a real bug (as of 2022-04-14), and was fixed by:

- in cython: [#4609](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4609)
- in CPython: [#90693](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90693) (originally: [bpo#46535](https://bugs.python.org/issue46535))
- in numpy: [#21008](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/21008)

Comment: Thank you for linking the relevant GitHub issues!

Answer (score 6):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71879536/6200607) is great.
But it should be updated.

### Short answer:

Upgrade Pandas --> `v1.4.3`

You should upgrade to `v1.4.3` of pandas. Then the code now behaves as expected in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks! -- the answer has been updated by @trs.

Answer (score 0):

See also [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71288331/matplotlib-typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-callable).

Apparently there is a PyCharm numpy.core module empty template that replaces the true numpy.core module and it interferes with the true module.