# debugger throws error whilst running script doesn't - statsmodels

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, statsmodels

This is the minimal reproducible example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    import numpy as np
    duncan_prestige = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Duncan", "carData")
    Y = duncan_prestige.data['income']
    X = duncan_prestige.data['education']
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    model = sm.OLS(Y, X)
    results = model.fit()
```

Without any breakpoints, running this with the debugger throws an error

```
... 
dtype = numeric.dtype(type(dtype)) 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable 
python-BaseException
```

Running it without the debugger seems to work just fine.

I'm using `Python 3.10.2` and `PyCharm 2022.2 (Community Edition)`.

And I kind of need to use the debugger to find out how to extract this
[image]
that appears when we run `print(results.summary())` at the end. I've managed to narrow the displayed table to a smaller table with `print(results.summary().tables[0])` but was helpless without a debugger.

Comment: Not sure, but it could be the same bug described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998276/how-to-fix-the-numpy-dtype-nonetype-error)

Comment: Downgrading to 3.9 did solve the problem ... temporarily

Comment: I is therefore probably the same bug described in the link you provided @AlexK