# Exception happens ONLY in PyCharm's debug mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Below is the code snippet

```py
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta

import pandas_market_calendars as mcal


def is_US_market_open(dt: date) -> bool:
    nyse = mcal.get_calendar("NYSE")
    return not nyse.schedule(start_date=dt, end_date=dt).empty


def gen_last_market_open_day_of_month() -> date:
    today = date.today()
    curr_year = today.year
    curr_month = today.month
    while curr_year > 0:
        last_day_of_month = datetime.date(curr_year, curr_month, 1) - timedelta(days=1)
        while not is_US_market_open(last_day_of_month):
            last_day_of_month -= timedelta(days=1)
        yield last_day_of_month
        curr_month -= 1
        if curr_month == 0:
            curr_month = 12
            curr_year -= 1
```

The above method `gen_last_market_open_day_of_month` works great EXCEPT in PyCharm's debug mode, it will raise the below exception if anyhow i try to debug the application...

I tried to set the `PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=NO` but still the exception pops up in the debug mode

```bash
***/.venv/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 60697 --file ***/src/utils/time.py 
warning: PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON environment variable is set to 'NO'. Frame evaluator will be also disabled because it requires Cython extensions to be enabled in order to operate correctly.
Connected to pydev debugger (build 231.9011.38)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas_market_calendars/market_calendar.py", line 461, in holidays
    try: return self._holidays
AttributeError: 'NYSEExchangeCalendar' object has no attribute '_holidays'. Did you mean: 'holidays'?

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py", line 670, in __init__
    self.dtype = numeric.dtype(int_type)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1496, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "***/src/utils/time.py", line 60, in <module>
    print(is_US_market_open(datetime.datetime.strptime("1999-12-31", FORMAT_YMD).date()))
  File "***/src/utils/time.py", line 41, in is_US_market_open
    return not nyse.schedule(start_date=dt, end_date=dt).empty
  File "***/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas_market_calendars/market_calendar.py", line 599, in schedule
    _all_days = self.valid_days(start_date, end_date)
  File "***/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas_market_calendars/exchange_calendar_nyse.py", line 1092, in valid_days
    trading_days = super().valid_days(start_date, end_date, tz= tz)
  File "***/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas_market_calendars/market_calendar.py", line 479, in valid_days
    return pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq=self.holidays(), normalize=True, tz=tz)
  File "***/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas_market_calendars/market_calendar.py", line 463, in holidays
    self._holidays = CustomBusinessDay(
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx", line 3272, in pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.CustomBusinessDay.__init__
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx", line 1302, in pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.BusinessMixin._init_custom
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx", line 252, in pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets._get_calendar
  File "***/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/tseries/holiday.py", line 454, in holidays
    pre_holidays = [
  File "***/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/tseries/holiday.py", line 455, in <listcomp>
    rule.dates(start, end, return_name=True) for rule in self.rules
  File "***/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/tseries/holiday.py", line 272, in dates
    np.in1d(holiday_dates.dayofweek, self.days_of_week)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in in1d
  File "***/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 655, in in1d
    range_safe_from_overflow = ar2_range <= np.iinfo(ar2.dtype).max
  File "***/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py", line 672, in __init__
    self.dtype = numeric.dtype(type(int_type))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

- Python 3.10.11
- pandas = "1.4.2"
- pandas-market-calendars = "~4.1.4"

Comment: Similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998276/how-to-fix-the-numpy-dtype-nonetype-error Answers there suggest upgrading Pandas to 1.4.3

Comment: @slothrop indeed, upgrade pandas to 1.4.3 solve the issue, thanks